# Why is *drawRect* not being called from the ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, drawrect, uipopover

I have an iPad app (XCode 5, iOS 7, Storyboards and ARC).  I have a `UIPopover` created in a `UIViewController`, and when I tap a button it correctly displays the popover.

Now, I want to draw a grid in that popover; I know I have to add code to `drawRect` do do the drawing, and do a `setNeedsDisplay` to get the drawing done.  However, it's not working!

My question is why is `drawRect` not being called when from `[popoverView setNeedsDisplay];` ?  Both methods are in the same UIViewController class.

Here is the code that is supposed to call the `drawRect`

```
//  create popover
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 650, 416)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(650.0, 416.0);

//  draw the lines, etc on the popoverContent
[popoverView setNeedsDisplay];

//  create the popover controller and attach the popover content to it
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate = (id)self;
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(650, 416) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(650, 416, 10, 50) inView: obViewOpenAppts
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

I have a breakpoint in `drawRect` so I know it's not being called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you creating a popoverView, but I don't see you setting it as the view for anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drawRect:` is a  UIView method, not a UIViewController method. If you want to override it you have to subclass UIView, and then create it like this:

```
MyUIViewSubclass *popoverView = [[MyUIViewSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 650, 416)];
```

Comment: Right, and it is invoking the default implementation, which you are not overriding. You just made a method in UIViewController called drawRect:.  You didn't override `[UIView -drawRect:]` because UIView is not UIViewController.

Comment: Right... I just saw that... it's a slow morning... :D

Comment: This is my interface code, for which I'm having problems overriding (I don't do it that often)    @interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>  {
    
}

Comment: That's your UIViewController interface. If you want to make a UIView subclass, make a new file.